# Existe um atalho para selecionar e modificar trechos semelhantes?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij

Gostaria de saber um atalho do Intellij IDEA semelhante ao <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> do Sublime, que seleciona todos os objetos semelhantes e é possível modificá-los em conjunto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No IntelliJ IDEA, experimente <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada !

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o botão do meio do mouse (o do scroll) e selecionar as linhas na vertical, ou usar o comando <kbd>Shit + Alt + Insert</kbd>, e usar as setas  para selecionar as linhas e colunas que desejar.

Espero que seja isto que você estava procurando.

Comment: Olá, obrigada, mas não era bem isso. Tipo eu tenho a palavra main, seleciono ela, dou crtl + D e todas as main são selecionadas, ai se quero modificar o nome eu só digito e todas as main do arquivo são alteradas simultaneamente, como no Sublime.

Comment: Agora entendi, é não conheço nenhum atalho para isso. Quando preciso fazer este tipo de edição uso o ctrl + F e dou um replace (um a um) ou replece all.

Comment: entendi, bem acredito que não deve haver então. É uma das coisas que economiza muito tempo e torna a vida mais pŕatica.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, esse é um atalhos que geralmente utilizo no Eclipse...

**Ex:** Click duas vezes no atributo que quer renomear, após utilize os atalhos...

```
Eclipse: alt+shift+r
```

Acredito que no IntelliJ IDEA seja:

```
IntelliJ: shift+F6
```

Fonte:
[IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse Shortcuts](https://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/intellij-idea-and-eclipse-shortcuts/)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esteja buscando o find and replace, utilize: Ctrl + r
digite no campo acima o que deseja alterar e no campo de baixo o novo valor para esse campo e clique em replace ou replace all para alterar todas as ocorrencias.
[image: Imagme do find and replace do intellij]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).